# how map same model twice by using JoinTable

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

In my requirements I have to have an entity named Account and another named Transaction. Transaction will contain the money transfered from one account to another.

For exemple: I can transfer money from John's account to Mary'account. I can transfer money from certain John's account to another John's account.

I am trying to solve this classical scenario using @JoinTable but somehow I lost some point and I am getting basically "ERROR: relation xxx does not exist"

full log

```
2018-01-27 20:51:55.601  INFO 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table account_sources drop constraint FK_d6jfyffrk9ydsf4keiu1yhkco
2018-01-27 20:51:55.606 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_sources drop constraint FK_d6jfyffrk9ydsf4keiu1yhkco
2018-01-27 20:51:55.607 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "account_sources" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table account_sources drop constraint FK_s8l8nq2u3yjvjd9rpwqj8u1x5
2018-01-27 20:51:55.607 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_sources drop constraint FK_s8l8nq2u3yjvjd9rpwqj8u1x5
2018-01-27 20:51:55.607 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "account_sources" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table account_targets drop constraint FK_j0xd4pvy0biudmtycc9fsja57
2018-01-27 20:51:55.608 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_targets drop constraint FK_j0xd4pvy0biudmtycc9fsja57
2018-01-27 20:51:55.608 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "account_targets" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table account_targets drop constraint FK_hjcwotogjscfgt6jovlm1kau7
2018-01-27 20:51:55.609 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table account_targets drop constraint FK_hjcwotogjscfgt6jovlm1kau7
2018-01-27 20:51:55.609 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "account_targets" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table accounts drop constraint FK_e4w4av1wrhanry7t6mxt42nou
2018-01-27 20:51:55.610 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table accounts drop constraint FK_e4w4av1wrhanry7t6mxt42nou
2018-01-27 20:51:55.610 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: constraint "fk_e4w4av1wrhanry7t6mxt42nou" of relation "accounts" does not exist
Hibernate: drop table if exists account_sources cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists account_targets cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists accounts cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists transactions cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists users cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2018-01-27 20:51:55.627 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2018-01-27 20:51:55.627 ERROR 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
Hibernate: create table account_sources (transactions_id int8 not null, sources_id int8 not null)
Hibernate: create table account_targets (transactions_id int8 not null, targets_id int8 not null)
Hibernate: create table accounts (id int8 not null, name varchar(255), user_id int8 not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table transactions (id int8 not null, amount numeric(19, 2), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table users (id int8 not null, address varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table account_sources add constraint FK_d6jfyffrk9ydsf4keiu1yhkco foreign key (sources_id) references accounts
Hibernate: alter table account_sources add constraint FK_s8l8nq2u3yjvjd9rpwqj8u1x5 foreign key (transactions_id) references transactions
Hibernate: alter table account_targets add constraint FK_j0xd4pvy0biudmtycc9fsja57 foreign key (targets_id) references accounts
Hibernate: alter table account_targets add constraint FK_hjcwotogjscfgt6jovlm1kau7 foreign key (transactions_id) references transactions
Hibernate: alter table accounts add constraint FK_e4w4av1wrhanry7t6mxt42nou foreign key (user_id) references users
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence
2018-01-27 20:51:55.690  INFO 7472 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

gets/sets
}
```

Account

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

//gets/sets
}
```

Transaction

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTIONS")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "account_sources")
    private List<Account> sources;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_targets")
    private List<Account> targets;

//gets/sets
}
```

schema-postgres.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users(id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), address VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE accounts(id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), user_id bigint not null references users (id));

CREATE TABLE transactions(
id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(100), 
account_sources bigint not null references accounts (id),
account_targets bigint not null references accounts (id)
);
```

Comment: Those are not really errors. SchemaExport just tries deleting your tables and constraints (probably because you configured Hibernate to drop and recreate the schema on startup), and since they don't exist, you get those traces in the logs. You said "Transaction will contain the money transact from **one** account to **another**". So why do you have two lists of accounts in Transaction?

Comment: I added a functional exemple. In few words I want create a kind of relationship which allows me to map certain entity twice: one will stand for source and another for target. Would you achive this in different approach? If so, how?

Comment: Well, as you, and I, just said, a transwaction is a transfer from **one** account to **another** account. So it should have a ManyToOne with a source account, and another ManyToOne to a target account. Not ManyToManys.

Comment: Ok, yo are write, if you want elaborate a bit more specially your first comment, I will set as answer. I believe the error message was caused by "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop". I took it out and now no more error as originally pasted in my question